# No instance(s) of type variable(s) Y exist so that Calendar conforms to LiveData<Y>

Tags: java, android, transformation, android-livedata, switchmap

I want my `LiveData<Calendar>` instance to change everytime `List` of `Alarms` change. I have following code:

```
private LiveData<Calendar> nextAlarm;

public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application app) {

    nextAlarm = Transformations.switchMap(alarmRepo.getAlarms(), alarms -> {
        Calendar nearest = null;
        // ... some necessary computation here (iterating through alarms):
        // foreach alarms, find nearest one, create new Calendar according to day and time saved in database
        return nearest;
    });
```

Error I see:

> No instance(s) of type variable(s) Y exist so that Calendar conforms

Can somebody help me out here? How can I return new Calendar instance in `SwitchMapFunction`?

> to LiveData

Comment: Please add more code, e.g. the imports you are using. Specifically: What is `LiveData`, what is `Calendar`, how are they related to each other.

Comment: There is a lot of computation, but I can say that Calendar is new object created from specific alarm's day and time.

Comment: `switchMap` returns `LiveData<Y>`, not `<Y>` - your `nearest` is not a `LiveData` object

Comment: OK, but how can I return `LiveData<Calendar>`? I cannot create it, since it is abstract class.

Comment: `MutableLiveData`?

Comment: I solved this with @HelloBird answer - I used `Transformations.map()`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need use `Transformation.map()` function instead of `Transformation.switchMap()`

Comment: One question - do `Transformations.map()` keep `Observers` working?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand,you want know Is observer will be called when alarms list changed?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if it will keep the observers connected to this livedata.

Comment: Yes, it will keep the observers connected to this livedata when observers active